# command not founde when running script file that runs java file

Tags: java, bash, assembly, makefile

We have a school assignment where we have to build an assembler that translates a file named file.asm and should output a file name file.hack. We did this using java (with a file named Main.java) and we are 100% sure the code works perfectly. However in order to submit it we have to add to the same folder two files: Makefile and a script called Assembler. These two files are given to us BUT they say that these might require edits depending on how our code works. Here is the Makefile:

```
###############################################################################
#
# Makefile for a Java project
#
###############################################################################

# **** Why do we need this file? ****
# We want our users to have a simple API to run the Assembler, no matter the language
# it was written in. So, we need a "wrapper" that will hide all language-specific details to do so,
# thus enabling our users to simply type 'Assembler <path>' in order to use it.

# **** What are makefiles? ****
# This is a sample makefile. 
# The purpose of makefiles is to make sure that after running "make" your project is ready for execution.

# **** What should I change in this file to make it work with my project? ****
# Usually, Java projects need to compile all java source files and give execution permissions for your 
# run file executable to run. The executable for project 6 should be called Assembler.
# Obviously, your project may be more complicated and require a different makefile.
# IMPORTANT 1: For this file to run when you call "make", rename it from "Makefile-java" to "Makefile".
# IMPORTANT 2: If your project requires more than simply setting execution permissions, define rules
#              accordingly.

# **** How are rules defined? ****
# The following line is a rule declaration: 
# all:
#   javac -encoding ISO-8859-1 *.java
#   chmod +x Assembler
        

# A makefile rule is a list of prerequisites (other rules that need to be run before this rule) and commands 
# that are run one after the other. The "all" rule is what runs when you call "make".
# In this example, all it does is compile all Java files in the current directory, and grant execution 
# permissions for your run time executable, so your project will be able to run on the graders' computers. 
# In this case, the "all" rule has no preqrequisites.

# A general rule looks like this:
# rule_name: prerequisite1 prerequisite2 prerequisite3 prerequisite4 ...
#   command1
#   command2
#   command3
#   ...
# Where each preqrequisite is a rule name, and each command is a command-line command (for example chmod, 
# javac, echo, etc').

# **** Beginning of the actual Makefile ****
# The following line is a declaration of a variable named JAVAC:
JAVAC=javac
# As you can see, the variable only holds the name of the java compiler.

# The JAVACFLAGS variable should include any special flags your program needs for compilation:
JAVACFLAGS=-encoding ISO-8859-1

# The SRCS variable should include the filenames of all .java source files relevant for your project:
SRCS=*.java
# It is currently defined to be all .java files in the current directory.

# The EXEC variable should include the name of the run file executable only.
# In the case of Project 6, it is "Assembler":
EXEC=Assembler

# Let's define more variables that we'll use later on:
TAR=tar
TARFLAGS=cvf
TARNAME=projXXX.tar
TARSRCS=$(SRCS) $(EXEC) Makefile

# The following line is a rule declaration. A makefile rule is a list of prerequisites (other rules that 
# need to be run before this rule) and commands that are run one after the other. The "all" rule is what 
# runs when you call "make":
all: compile

# As you can see, the "all" rule requires the "compile" rule. Meaning, that when you call the 
# "all" rule, the "compile" rule is called too. 

# The "compile" rule performs a compilation of all java files specified in the SRCS variable
# and then gives execution permissions to the run file called Assembler
compile:
    $(JAVAC) $(JAVACFLAGS) $(SRCS)
    chmod +x $(EXEC)
    
# The "compile" rule simply runs two commands one after the other:
# 1. "$(JAVAC) $(JAVACFLAGS) $(SRCS)" - this command is constructed from 3 variables, and if you use 
# the defaults specified here it simply translated to "javac *.java", meaning that it compiles all 
# java files in the current directory.
# 2. "chmod +x $(EXEC)" - this command is constructed from "chmod +x", which is the terminal command 
# that grants execution permissions, and "$(EXEC)", which should contain the name of your run file. 
# This command simply gives execution permissions for your run file, so the graders could run it on their
# computers.

# The following rule allows you to call "make tar". It will put all the files specified
# in the TARSRCS variable in a tar. This is for your convenience only and you don't have to support it.
tar:
    $(TAR) $(TARFLAGS) $(TARNAME) $(TARSRCS)

# The following rules allows you to call "make clean". It will remove all compiled class files. 
# This is for your convenience only and you don't have to support it.   
clean:
    rm -f *.class *~
```

and here is the Assembler script:

```
# **** Why do we need this file? ****
# The purpose of this file is to run your project.
# We want our users to have a simple API to run the Assembler, no matter the language
# it was written in. So, we need a "wrapper" that will hide all language-specific details to do so,
# thus enabling our users to simply type 'Assembler <path>' in order to use it.

# **** What are '#!/bin/sh' and '$*'? ****
# '$*' is a variable that holds all the arguments this file has received. So, if you
# run "Assembler-java trout mask replica", $* will hold "trout mask replica".

# **** What should I change in this file to make it work with my project? ****
# IMPORTANT 1: The only two lines the file should contain are '#!/bin/sh' (which means that this file is a 
#              script) and the command you use to run your project.
# IMPORTANT 1: For this file to run when you call "Assembler", rename it from "Assembler-java" to "Assembler".
# IMPORTANT 2: This file assumes that the main is contained in "Main.java".
#              If your main is contained elsewhere, you will need to change this.

#!/bin/sh
java Main $*
```

Our project has the following structure:
Assembler
Main.java
Makefile

We do the following:
int the terminal we run the command:
make
this adds execution permissions to the file Assembler and creates the class Main.class
then we run:
./Assembler pathtofile/file.asm
and then this uses our java code and we get a file.hack as output as requested BUT in the terminal we get the following messages outputted:
: command not founde 6:
: command not founde 10:
: command not founde 17:

We checked and there is no way these messages come from the java file. Even though this does not affect the outputted hack file, we were still told this should not happen but we do not know where to start as the previously mentioned files do not give us any clues. Any idea how to fix this? (Me and my partner have been working for a long time so would appreciate any clue or idea, THANK YOU)

Comment: A hint which might help the script work, read **IMPORTANT 1:**

Comment: 6, 10 and 17 is where the empty lines are...are you using a CRLF file in a unix environment?

Comment: `command not founde 6:` there seems to be a typo in the error messages, and the message doesn't seem to be complete. On [so] please **always** directly copy the error messages including details into the question (or in this case at least one time, no need for repeated errors). On a side node: this is an issue with the environment and a great question to ask a teacher or teacher's assistant.

Comment: First of all thank you for responding! @DuncG are you saying I should delete the comments? My assumption was that comments and empty lines would not affect the script. I do not believe we are using a CRLF

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yes I have asked the TA and have not received a response. This is the complete error message

Comment: "command not founde" has a spelling error and is missing details, I think it could be generated by a script created for evaluating your answers. Ask other students or kick assistant.

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem was indeed the empty lines!!

Comment: I'd still kick the assistant for not answering; that is unexpected behavior.

Comment: By the way please see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/577663/handling-bash-script-with-crlf-carriage-return-in-linux-as-in-msys2) to understand the details. There are various utilities to convert the line endings such as `dos2unix` or invocations of `sed` / `awk` / `tr` and whatnot that require additional parameters / coding.

Comment: @Maria Executable scripts should normally have line one starting with `#!` followed by exact path to the script interpreter - `/bin/sh` in your case.